# Why <video> or direct video cannot show or play with cefsharp

Tags: video, html5-video, cefsharp

I ran the CefSharp.MinimalExample > CefSharp.WinForms project.
(https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample)
But when I want to open a video directly, I can't see it.

For example video url: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4

Sometimes can not auto play video.
Example url: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay
Example html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The video autoplay attribute</h1>

<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

debug.log

```
[0523/131717.003:ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(26)] MediaEvent: MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: no supported streams"}
[0523/131717.003:ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(26)] MediaEvent: PIPELINE_ERROR DEMUXER_ERROR_NO_SUPPORTED_STREAMS
```

Why  or direct video cannot show or play with cefsharp?

Comment: Mp4 files are typically h264 encoded which is not freely available. Only freely licenced codecs are supported see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo

Comment: But open some times 
[this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay)  

Why some times play some times fire exception?  I think buffer or cache load error.

Comment: Make sure you are testing with version 81, the example was updated recently. What does and doesn't play is entirely handled by Chromium, upgrading to new versions is the only control we have.